# OpenGL Framebuffer with multiple Depthbuffers inside

Tags: opengl, frame-buffer, virtual-reality

I am trying to put multiple depthbuffers into one Framebuffer.
I want to use VR and render both eyes at the same time:

that means, in the geometry stage I want to clone the incoming triangle to two outgoing triangles with a shift of the eye offset for layered rendering. Therefore I would like to have two RGB textures / maybe one RGB texture 2d array and two depthbuffers / a depthbuffer array

here is my program code so far, the error occurred at the second last line of code and it is a GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

```
GLError();
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_sFrameBufferInfo.m_nFrameBuffer);
GLError();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_sFrameBufferInfo.m_nFrameBuffer);

//Left eye
GLuint textureLeft;
glGenTextures(1, &textureLeft);
GLError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLeft);
GLError();

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, m_nWindowWidth, m_nWindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
GLError();

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLError();
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLeft, 0);
GLError();

//right eye
GLuint textureRight;
glGenTextures(1, &textureRight);
GLError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureRight);
GLError();

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, m_nWindowWidth, m_nWindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
GLError();

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLError();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLError();
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureRight, 0);
GLError();

//depth buffer
GLuint textureDepth;

glGenTextures(1, &textureDepth);
GLError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureDepth);
GLError();

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, m_nWindowWidth, m_nWindowHeight,2 , 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, NULL);
GLError();

glFramebufferTexture3D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureDepth, 2, 0);
GLError();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLError();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBOs can only use a single depth image, but that image *can* be layered. Broadly speaking, VR multi-eye rendering ought to be done through layered FBO images for both the color and depth buffers.

The problem with your code is that you can't use `glFramebufferTexture3D` to attach a layered image. You must use `glFramebufferTexture`.

Also, you need to use layers for the color image as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! when layering both (color and depth) everything is working...